# Отправка данных на Spring MVC контроллер используя ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

Пытаюсь отправить данные контроллеру используя ajax, но метод в контроллере не вызывается, если отправляю больше одного параметра. Код метода в контроллере:

```
@Timed
@RequestMapping(value = "saveee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JsonResultBean saveTicketTemplate(@RequestBody TicketTemplateFieldBean fieldBean, Long id) throws IOException {
    //TODO smth
    return JsonResultBean.success();
}
```

Код ajax'а, с которым все работает:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/organizer/api/saveee',
            data: JSON.stringify(fieldBean.data),
            success: function(result) {
                //TODO
            }
        })
```

Но стоит изменить data, и метод в конртоллере даже не вызывается:

```
data: ({'fieldBean': JSON.stringify(fieldBean.data), 'id': id})
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: можете добавить класс `TicketTemplateFieldBean` ?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте переписать ajax запрос следующим образом. Я так понимаю, он у вас срабатывает при каком-то ивенте. Допустим онклик. На баттон, который обрабатывает данный запрос добавьте `<input type="button" onclick="save()"/>`.

Будет вызываться данная функция:

```
function save(){ 

var TicketTemplateFieldBean = {

        fieldBean : // сюда можете передавать данные через 
                    //параметры функции или запрашивать их с 
                    //помощью jquery по айди тега.
        id : id(значения которое передаете в параметре) или $("#id").val()
}

$.ajax({

    url : "/organizer/api/saveee",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(TicketTemplateFieldBean),
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(data) {
        alert('save');
    },
    error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert('adding component failed with status: ' + status + ". "
                + errorThrown);
    }

});
}
```

В этом варианте, очень важно, чтобы поля и имя класса `TicketTemplateFieldBean` совпадали с полями в передаваемом в контроллер json'е. 
Если у вас в `TicketTemplateFieldBean` поле записано как field, а в json'e как fieldBean вы получите тоже ошибку. 
Этот вариант подходит для передачи нескольких параметров json'ом. В случае если вы передаете только один параметр, его использовать не очень то и логично.

Это первое.
Второе. Насколько мне известно `@RequestBody` в параметре контроллера принимает класс, который уже приходит на контроллер в формате JSON, по этому второй параметр `Long id` он само собой не видит, так как это уже не в его компетенции. 
Для того, чтобы передать единственный параметр json'ом используйте аннотацию `@PathVariable`, но использовать ее несколько раз в одном методе, в качестве нескольких параметров так же не получится. Придется написать класс, поля которого будут отвечать полям передаваемого объекта.